# Dartlang: Using enums in Angular2 templates

Tags: angular, enums, dart, angular2-template, angular-dart

can someone tell me if and how it is possible to use Dart enums in angular2 view templates?

It's suggested in Typescript to copy the enum into a component-scope. 
This works because an enum in javascript is a simple instance variable with a prototype.

But since enums in dart are first class citizens, they cannot be moved to an instance variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you should your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We're working on bringing formal support, but you can always add a getter for now:

```
enum MyEnum {
  stateA,
  stateB,
}

class MyComponent {
  MyEnum get stateA => MyEnum.stateA;
}
```

Comment: could you add a link here to the github issue? so we can subscribe

Comment: @Jonathan looks like this has been solved, by the other answer

Comment: @RyanHaining true. Maybe OP could change the correct answer. Would benefit others

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`exports` property of your Component class](https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular/angular/Component/exports). Copied from [here in the AngularDart Guide](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/template-syntax#expression-context).

```
enum MyEnum { foo, bar, baz }

@Component(
  selector: 'example',
  exports: const [MyEnum],
  template: '<p>{{MyEnum.bar}}</p>',
)
class Example {}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.